# If treble product of first 2 digits

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that should be able to calculate the product of first n-1 digits.
Note: If treble first 2 digits.

The code is working when 4 digits entered , example : 1234 , product is 6 . Cant figure out the treble part

So far I tried this, but no solution:

```
 using namespace std;
 int main()
{

int n , sum = 0, s,d,k,w, product ;
cout <<"Enter number: " << endl;
cin >> n;

if ((n>1) && (n<10000)) {
{
 s= n/10;
    d = n/100%10; // 2.
    k = n/1000%100%10; //1.
    w = n/10%10; //3.
//1234
   product = w*d*k;


  if ((n>1) && (n<1000)) {
       s = n/10;
    d = n/100%10; // 2.
    k = n/1000%100%10; //1.
    w = n/10%10; //3.

    product = k*d;

}
     cout <<"Sum of digits inp numb is : " << d+k+w  << " and product is : " << product  <<  endl;

     cout << "w: " << w << " k: " << k << " d: " << d << " s: " << s << endl;

   }
 }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you be a little more clear about what a 'treble' is, I am slightly confused, do you mean as in triple?

Comment: I think you should use a debug tool -> and some pen and paper ;)  this would be good for your code understanding...

Comment: You mean you want something like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JIaKlSHnE7vBA9lF)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if ((n>1) && (n<1000)) {
       s = n/10;
    d = n/100%10; // 2.
    k = n/1000%100%10; //1.
    w = n/10%10; //3.

    product = k*d;

}
```

This part should be your "treble" part. This line is the issue:

```
product = k*d;.
```

If `n < 1000`, then k becomes `0%100%10` which is `0`. Thus your product is 0. I think your intention was:

```
product = w*d;
```

For the general solution, repeatedly divide and take the running product of the modulus. Like this:

```
n = n/10;
product = 1;
while (n > 0){
    product = product * (n%10);
    n = n/10;
}
```